# mysql: user profile image is not saving in database,

Tags: php, mysqli

A.o.A
  i working on user profile page and when i upload pic its not saving in database and not showing in browser,,, only saving in uploads folder

```
<?php
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "jobsdb");
    if (isset($_POST['upload'])) 
    {
      $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];

      $sql = "update users set user_image='$image' where 
    username='$user_id'";
      mysqli_query($db, $sql);

      $target = "uploads/".basename($image);
      echo $_SESSION['user_id'];

     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
     {
       $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
     }  else
        {
          $msg = "Failed to upload image";
        }
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE 
    user_image='image'");

  ?>

  <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
      echo "<img src='uploads/".$row['user_image']."' >";
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: Firstly, you need to declare `session_start();` at the top of the page after the `<?php tags`. You also need to set `$user_id` as it hasn't been set. Your query's are also open to SQL Injection. I suggest using prepared statements. Your structure to how you're implementing your methods also needs to be corrected.

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE 
    user_image='$image'");

Comment: besides the SQL Injection vulnerabilities ,  this query is totally wrong`SELECT * FROM users WHERE 
    user_image='image'` unless every image is named `image` even then you get every row.

Comment: @SanjitBhardwaj - you shouldn't show bad query practices.  File names can be used for some SQL attacks, probably.  So concatenating the names of them right into SQL, probably a not so good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php

    session_start();//missing
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "jobsdb");
    if (isset($_POST['upload'])) 
    {
  $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
  $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];//initialize the variable 
  $sql = "update users set user_image='$image' where 
username='$user_id'";
  mysqli_query($db, $sql);

  $target = "uploads/".basename($image);


 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 {
   $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
 }  else
    {
      $msg = "Failed to upload image";
    }
}
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE 
user_image='$image'");

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
 {
  echo "<img src='uploads/".$row['user_image']."' >";
  }
?>
```

Comment: i hv already started session at top of page:   <?php session_start(); if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) { $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first"; header('location: login.php'); } if (isset($_GET['logout'])) { session_destroy(); unset($_SESSION['username']); header("location: login.php"); } $user_id = ""; $_SESSION['user_id'] = ""; ?>

Comment: why $_SESSION['user_id'] = "";, there is no initialization of $user_id

Comment: $user_id = "";
$_SESSION['user_id'] = ""; first it it is initialized

Answer (score 0):

What's the type of the column you save the value `user_image`?

Also you could make a base64_encode for the image like

```
$data = file_get_contents('uploads/'.basename($image));
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```

and store it in your database as a **LONGTEXT** type so you don't need to store it on a folder too.

Comment: @Umar maybe the main issue is that **text type** can't store that amount of data. try changing to **LONGTEXT** or  **MEDIUMBLOB** to store this kind of values and tell us if it helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
session_start(); //to initiate session before executing php script.  
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');  //Check the image size which to be uploaded
```

Try to create folder in the server for images to be stored. Move uploaded the file  to the particular folder and Store only related path in the database column

Answer (score 0):

Put below line on top of the screen:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Check db connection:

```
<?php
    $db_username = "db_username";  // Your database login username 
    $db_password = "db_password";  // Your database login password
    $db_name = "db_name";      // The name of the database you wish to use
    $db_host = "db_host";   // The address of the database. Often this is 
    localhost, but may be for example db.yoursite.com
    $conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
?>
```

Do you get `"Image uploaded successfully"` message?